# Celery waking up in 5.00 seconds

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

Why Celery beat is always waking up in 5s while I don't have any enabled task?

Is there a way to remove/change this period from 5s to 10m for example?

Logs:

```
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:11,936: INFO/Beat] DatabaseScheduler: Schedule changed.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:11,936: DEBUG/Beat] Writing entries...
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:11,969: DEBUG/Beat] DatabaseScheduler: Fetching database schedule
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:11,974: DEBUG/Beat] Current schedule:
web_1      | 
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:12,013: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:17,025: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:22,033: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:27,044: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:32,059: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:37,068: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:42,080: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:47,095: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:52,108: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:43:57,121: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:44:02,131: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:44:07,140: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:44:12,147: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:44:17,165: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:44:22,177: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:44:27,199: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:44:32,205: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:44:37,223: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:44:42,230: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:44:47,242: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:44:52,254: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:44:57,262: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:45:02,276: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:45:07,289: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:45:12,304: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:45:17,313: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
web_1      | [2021-03-03 09:45:22,326: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
```

I'm using:

```
celery==5.0.5
django-celery-beat==2.2.0
django-redis==4.11.0
redis==3.2.0
```

This is how I start Celery:

```
celery -A project worker --beat --scheduler django --concurrency=2 -Ofair --loglevel=debug --task-events
```

I understood that probably the problem is related to timezone, but I'm using UTC at TZ.

```
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_STORE_ERRORS_EVEN_IF_IGNORED = True
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True 
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC' 
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15
# BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 10 
# BROKER_HEARTBEAT_CHECKRATE = 2.0
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Celery Beat has to run regularly in order to schedule things. This isn't a problem and doesn't use much in the way of resources. The only reason you're seeing this is that logging is set to "debug" level which can be somewhat noisy.

Comment: Thanks, Robert, is there a way to change this period from 5s to 5m for example? (I don't have many tasks right now, just 1 task that executes once daily)

Comment: I don't know of any way to change this- but I also don't know why it would matter. This is standard behavior for daemons.